# Lists of chukkim and mishpatim?

Tags: mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

There are two types of commandments: chukkim and mishpatim.  Mishpatim are those for which a good reason quickly comes to mind, such as "Do not steal".  Chukkim are those for which a good reason does not come to mind, such as the red heifer.

Did commentators compile lists of the commandments they deem to be chukkim?  Or, since what sounds like a mishpat to one person could be a mysterious chok to another, none tried?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In "Chorev" [R. Samson Raphael Hirsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch) divides the Torah into several categories, two of which are *mishpatim* and *chukim*. Here is an image of [the table of contents](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22166&st=&pgnum=4), showing which *mitzvot* are classed in each category:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]